# I need postgresql version of this function

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, stored-functions

I am newbie to postgresql and I need a postgresql version of this function - could you help me please?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getpersonname]
    (@commid INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @personnname varchar(255)

    SELECT 
        @personnname = COALESCE(@personname + ',', '') + 
                       ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), pers.personnname  ),'')
    FROM 
        dbo.comlink comli  
    INNER JOIN 
        dbo.person pers ON personid= comli_personid
    WHERE  
        comli.comli_commid = @commid

    RETURN @personnname 
END
```

Comment: What does the function do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand that code correctly it returns all names separated with commas.

That can easily be done with a simple SQL statement in Postgres:

```
create FUNCTION get_person_name(p_commid int)
   RETURNS text
AS
$$
    SELECT string_agg(pers.personnname, ',')
    FROM dbo.comlink comli  
      JOIN dbo.person pers ON personid = comli_personid
    WHERE  comli.comli_commid= p_commid;
$$
language sql;
```

Comment: This can also be done in SQL Server using the same query in SQL Server 2017 and Azure SQL Database, which support `STRING_AGG`.